# Why has IPv6 mngtmpaddr stopped responding?

Tags: ssh, nfs, ipv6

19.04

I have been using IPv6 on my LAN for a few weeks now. Ping, SSH, NFS -- all fine. Three 19.04 machines, all good.

Yesterday, after an update, the IPv6 stopped working. Processing a request to an IPv6 address on the LAN the system hangs. I say 'after an update' because I did do an update and some hours later I noticed the problem; so I'm not saying the update caused it, just noting the coincidence.

I had been using the  `mngtmpaddr` address as reported by the ip a command. On a try I switched to using the other IPv6 address (the /128 address) and now that one works.

This is not only a curiousity. There's an issue for me because I have been using my NFS server's IPv6 address to mount its shares when I'm away from the LAN. Previously I had to change my `/etc/fstab` whenever I was away from home. So :
So what is going on?

1. What is the difference between these two addresses?
2. Why would the `mngtmpaddr` stop working?
3. Will this change still work from outside the LAN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I see that the IPv6 addresses expire -- unless assigned otherwise. This default is, I believe, to protect the privacy of *clients*. This concern however is at odds with the requirement that *servers* have a consistent address.

So *that's* why the IPv6 addresses stopped working.

To acquire a 'static' - permanent - IPv6 I have added a IPv6 address to the netplan configuration.

```
  renderer: networkd
  wifis:
    wlp3s0:
      dhcp4: yes -- set through DHCP reservation
      dhcp6: no
      addresses: [10.0.0.120/24,"-:-:-:-::-/128"]
```

Where I took the IPv6 address from the current dynamically assigned IPv6 address, and the gateway from the `default` route of the `ip -6 r` command. (I found I had to reboot the machine to apply. A simple `netplan apply` or `networking restart` did not suffice.)

This assigns a `forever` lifetime to the IPv6 address and creates another temporary IPv6.

One of my three machines (all fully updated 19.04) resists creating a `forever` lifetime. I have fixed this with

```
ip a change <device IPv6 address> dev <device id> preferred_lft forever
```